# Vue cli service worker disabling

Tags: node.js, vue.js, service-worker, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I can't figure out how to stop my browsers from caching old versions of my web app. I have already commented out everything in `registerServiceWorker.js`. I deleted the cache from the browsers. In Chrome I've unregistered the service worker and set the checkbox on `Update on reload`. But I still get an old version of the website. Heck, I even restarted my Macbook.

What else can I do to see the current version of my website?